# Why would a DELETE statement NOT delete in one pass all records that meet the conditions?

Tags: mysql, timeout, mysql-5.7

I have this SQL statements that attempts to delete ALL **duplicate** rows that has one of its fields set to NULL. "Duplicate" means having same value in 4 fields only (col1,col4,col5,col6).

```
  DELETE
  FROM owndb.tbl1
  WHERE tbl1.id IN
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM
        (
          SELECT x2.id
          FROM
            owndb.tbl1 x2
            INNER JOIN tbl2 y2 ON x2.col5 = y2.id
            INNER JOIN tbl3 z2 ON x2.col1 = z2.id
            INNER JOIN
              (
                SELECT x1.id, x1.col1, x1.col2, z1.col3, x1.col4, x1.col5, y1.col6, 
                       COUNT(x1.col1), COUNT(x1.col4), COUNT(x1.col5), COUNT(y1.col6)
                FROM owndb.tbl1 x1
                  INNER JOIN tbl2 y1 ON x1.col5 = y1.id
                  INNER JOIN tbl3 z1 ON x1.col1 = z1.id
                GROUP BY x1.col1, x1.col5, x1.col4, y1.col6
                HAVING
                  COUNT(x1.col1)     > 1
                  AND COUNT(x1.col5) > 1
                  AND COUNT(x1.col4) > 1
                  AND COUNT(y1.col6) > 1
              ) AS dups
              ON
                x2.col1     = dups.col1
                AND x2.col5 = dups.col5
                AND x2.col4 = dups.col4
                AND y2.col6 = dups.col6
        ) AS ids
    )
    AND tbl1.col2 IS NULL
```

- When run on a database with about 40 million rows in tbl1, the
  statement above indeed deletes most of the duplicates (about 0.5
  million) but keeps leaving some undeleted. It takes **about** 10
  minutes to execute.
- When run again, it again deletes most of the
  leftover duplicates (about 80 thousand) but keeps leaving some
  undeleted. It again takes **about** 10 minutes to execute.
- When run again, it again deletes most of the leftover duplicates but keeps
  leaving some undeleted. Again, about 10 minutes to execute.
- And so on and so on... after about 20 such runs, **all** duplicates are finally
  deleted.

Why? Why would this DELETE statement **not** delete, in a single pass, all records that meet the conditions?

Suspecting some form of a timeout condition, I checked the value of `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME`. It is 0. The documentation says "The execution timeout for SELECT statements, in milliseconds. If the value is 0, timeouts are NOT enabled."

Also, looking at the logs, I see that about 5x rows are being examined:

```
# Query_time: 860.938912  Lock_time: 0.001816 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 195,651,505
# Query_time: 888.031845  Lock_time: 0.000881 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 195,679,037
# Query_time: 918.936984  Lock_time: 0.001823 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 195,647,462
# Query_time: 864.034052  Lock_time: 0.002571 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 195,641,058
# Query_time: 907.320618  Lock_time: 0.001008 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 195,645,355
```

What do I need to do in order for a **single run** to delete all such records, taking as long as it takes?

Comment: Did you look in the logs? If something got kicked out for some reason there shoudl be something in the logs

Comment: I have not investigated this query logic and correctness, but the description looks like the query deletes only one of N duplicates, and N-1 remains. Next execution deletes one more row, remaining N-2 duplicates, and so on until only one row remains.

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina MySQL 5.7.29b  I verified that only a single duplicate exists "per duplication". One has that col2 NULL and one doesn't.

Comment: This is a very complicated query for such a simple requirement. Did you search SO for similar cases? Maybe you just need a simpler query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I looked in the logs and didn't notice anything that got kicked out. What should I be looking for? I know that MyQSL has additional limitations on queries, such as max joins, max records, etc. but I need better understanding of what's going on in order to pinpoint the root cause.